# Creating an empty node

Tags: c, list, null, allocation

I am trying to create an empty node without affecting the pointer which points on the head of the connected list/node. So, is there is any problem in my code?

```
 CellPtr Create_Node(CellPtr created, int size)
    {
        CellPtr head;
        int i;
        if((created=(CellPtr)malloc(sizeof(Cell)))==NULL)
        {
            printf("Allocation Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        head=created;
        for(i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        {
            if((created->next=(CellPtr)malloc(sizeof(Cell)))==NULL)
            {
            printf("Allocation Error");
            exit(1);
            }
            created=created->next;
        }
        created->next=NULL;

    return head;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code is trying to accomplish? It appears to be creating a new set of empty node***s***. What is the purpose of passing in `created`; it's immediately overwritten.

Comment: don't do typedef of pointers, don't cast malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is you're passing in `created` but immediately overwriting it. I don't know why `created` is passed in.

It seems you're trying to make a new linked list with `size` + 1 empty cells. I would suggest splitting this into two pieces, one to create an empty cell, and one to add empty cells.

Stylistically, pointer types are confusing. It breaks the simple visual convention that `*` means pointer. Let's get rid of that.

```
typedef struct _Cell {
    struct _Cell *next;
} Cell;
```

Then we have one function to make and initialize an empty cell. This [DRYs up the code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). And [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

```
Cell *CreateCell() {
    Cell *cell = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
    if( cell == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation of Cell failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    cell->next = NULL;

    return cell;
}
```

Then a separate function to add empty cells to an existing cell. I've decided to return the new tail because that seems useful.

```
Cell *AddCells(Cell *tail, size_t num_cells) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num_cells; i++) {
        tail->next = CreateCell();
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    return tail;
}
```

Now we can create a cell, add to it, and efficiently have the new tail should we need it.

```
Cell *head = CreateCell();
Cell *tail = AddCells(head, 5);
```

And we can add cells to the tail of any existing linked list.

Comment: Thanks I understood it. Appreciate it